# Determine Intersection given only a hyperrectangle and a point-contained-in-shape-Predicate

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Given only an n-dimensional hyperrectangle by its corner-point-values and an n-dimensional Predicate that corresponds to an arbitrary shape and tests whether a point is contained in said shape,

is it possible to calculate whether the box intersects the shape?

Comment: What is a "shape" here? As long as this shape has one isolated point, it is clearly impossible, so the shape will have to be regular in some sense.

Comment: Convex would do, but in general any shape that can be represented by a coherent set.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is a black-box function to test containment in your shape $S$, then the answer is no in general. For example, take $n=2$, let your rectangle $R$ have corners $(\pm1,\pm1)$ and let $S$ be a disk. Note that $S$ can have exactly 1 point of intersection with our rectangle and this can be *any* point on the boundary of the rectangle. So, since we work over $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have to test an infinite number of points and hence it is impossible. (obviously, if we have a discretized space, the rectangle has a finite number of points and we can simple test all of those.)

---

So, if you can have an intersection with only 1 point at an infinite number of places, it is impossible. This can happen for a large class of shapes. The first counter-example I can think of is when $S$ is an axis-parallel rectangle with a minimum side-length $w>0$. $S$ can intersect at one point only in the 4 corners. If $S$ does intersect $R$, but not intersect in a corner $S$ must intersect a segment of length $w$ on the boundary of $R$, so we can test $\approx \frac{4}{w}$ values on the boundary of $R$ to find the intersection.

Note that even in this case, you need $O(\frac{1}{w})$ tests to determine intersections. I think this means that unless you make some strong assumptions about $S$ or relax your condition of intersection, this problem is not solvable.

Comment: Could you come up with strong assumptions about S that would change the picture? Because I couldn't. What kind of relaxations on the intersection would you imagine? Excluding one-point-intersection obviously yields little as you argued.

No discrete space by the way. And thanks.

Comment: I think that it might be nessecary to assume $S$ is a union of axis-parallel (assuming $R$ is axis-parallel) (hyper)rectangles of minimum width $w$. Otherwise, (I think) $S$ can always be translated such that it only intersects an arbitrary small segment or point on some boundary of $R$.

Comment: What I mean by relaxations is, for example, you are fine with having a algorithm that finds an intersection only if the intersection is 'nice', e.g. it contains a ball of radius at least $\varepsilon$. In this case, there is a finite sized grid of points in $R$ of which at least one lies in $S$ if the intersection is 'nice'. But I think that the main takeaway is that it is likely that this formalization is not a good way to solve your problem, i.e. it is genarally not possible to find all intersections when we can only query containment for one shape, so try something else.